# How to show images respecting their relative size?

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib

Images of different shapes stored in a list, are displayed as follow:
[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
H = ceil(sqrt(len(good_images)))
W = 1+len(good_images)//ceil(sqrt(len(good_images)))
print(len(good_images),H, W)
for i,im in enumerate(good_images):
        plt.subplot(H, W, i+1,xticks=[],yticks=[])
        plt.title(im.shape)
        plt.imshow(im, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray_r)
```

Is it possible to display the images and to conserve their relative size?

Comment: This is certainly possible by a number of ways but will require some fiddling.  Personally, I would put all the cell images in one axes and change their “extent” using that kwarg to imshow.  You’d have to loop through all the images once to figure out how wide and tall to make each column and row, but that isn’t too hard.  You can do the same with the axes positions if you want mxn axes but it’s more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may share the axes such that all images live on the same scales.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 25
f = lambda n,m: np.random.rand(n,m)
g = lambda: f(np.random.randint(29,150), np.random.randint(29,150))
images = [g() for _ in range(N)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,5, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for image, ax in zip(images, axs.flat):
    ax.imshow(image, cmap="Greys")
    ax.set_title(image.shape, fontsize=8)
    ax.autoscale()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]